# How to change an int outside a for loop

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays

I wrote an algorithm where I want it to use a random array of numbers and add the first and last numbers in that array. Example: My array is [0,5,3,8,2,4,7,9,6,1] and my algorithm should check if 1+5=6+0, and since it's not, it should check if 5+3=9+6, then if 3+8=7+9, and so on...

My first for loop is where the last numbers in the array are being checked. The problem is that the int `totalOfLastValues` is only being updated inside the for loop and so last values are not even being incremented. For example, in the array [0,5,3,8,2,4,7,9,6,1], 0+5=6+1 is not true, so it checks if 5+3=6+1 instead of checking if 5+3=9+6.

**In my `.h`**

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end
int totalOfLastValues;
int end;
int almost;
```

**In my `.m`**

```
-(void) numberAlgorithm {
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        int randomNumbers = arc4random_uniform(10);
        [arrayOfNumbers addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: randomNumbers]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfNumbers);

    int lastValue = [arrayOfNumbers count]-1;
    for (int p = lastValue; p > 2; p--) {
        end = [arrayOfNumbers[0 + p] integerValue];
        almost = [arrayOfNumbers[(0-1) + p] integerValue];
        totalOfLastValues = end + almost;            
    }

    int mostRecentValue  = [arrayOfNumbers[0] integerValue];
    for (int i = 1; i < [arrayOfNumbers count]-2; i++) {
        int one = mostRecentValue;
        int two = [arrayOfNumbers[i] integerValue];
        mostRecentValue = two;

        if ((one + two) == totalOfLastValues) {
            NSLog(@"2: Because %@ + %@ = %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i-1],arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[(0-1) + lastValue],arrayOfNumbers[0 + lastValue]);
            break;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"-1: Because %@ + %@ != %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i-1],arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[(0-1) + lastValue],arrayOfNumbers[0 + lastValue]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, I think this might be of help to you:

```
int arrLength = (int)[arrayOfNumbers count];
for (int x = 0; x < arrLength/2; x++) {
    if(x < arrLength-1) {
        NSLog(@"%i + %i compare %i + %i", [arrayOfNumbers[x] intValue], [arrayOfNumbers[x+1] intValue], [arrayOfNumbers[(arrLength-1) - x] intValue], [arrayOfNumbers[(arrLength-2) - x] intValue]);
    }
}
```

The output I get

```
2014-02-08 04:36:54.517 Test[54846:70b] (
    3,
    5,
    3,
    6,
    4,
    4,
    6,
    6,
    5,
    6
)
2014-02-08 04:36:54.518 Test[54846:70b] 3 + 5 compare 6 + 5
2014-02-08 04:36:54.519 Test[54846:70b] 5 + 3 compare 5 + 6
2014-02-08 04:36:54.520 Test[54846:70b] 3 + 6 compare 6 + 6
2014-02-08 04:36:54.520 Test[54846:70b] 6 + 4 compare 6 + 4
2014-02-08 04:36:54.521 Test[54846:70b] 4 + 4 compare 4 + 4
```